# Cartesian product with checking condition when adding a new element to the set and without a repeat of elements

Tags: c#, algorithm, cartesian-product

### There are two sets of:

1. int Transformer substations
2. object Buildings(the set is larger than the first set at least by 5 times).
   The building has 2 parameters (number and load).

   Need to create all possible combinations: each transformer station is loaded by 60-80% in every combination, and buildings don't repeat.

   Glad to hear any suggestions.

Tried the Cartesian product but I have no idea how to apply it. Ideas just don't appear. I guess it is because of the stress produced by the war in Ukraine where I live.

Comment: So a transformer has any number of buildings, and the problem is to create every possible distribution of Transformer:Buildings such that each Transformer is loaded to 60-80% capacity.. and then pick a winning combination some how?

Comment: @CaiusJard yep. There will be several winning combinations. Need them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **cartesian product** without elements repetition in any given result set and without permutations:

```
static void combinations(List<List<string>> srs, int[] size, List<string> curr, int index)
{
    if (index == srs.Count())
    {     
        int s = curr.Count();
        string[] d = new string[s];
        List<string> x = d.ToList();
        x.AddRange(curr);
        x.RemoveAll(item => item == null);
        dest.Add(x);
        string res = "";
        foreach (var item in x)
        {
            res += item + ", ";
        }
        //dest.add(d);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size[index]; i++)
        {
            int n = size[index];
            string[] dim = new string[n];
            dim = srs[index].ToArray();
            curr.Add(dim[i]);
            index++;
            combinations(srs, size, curr, index);
            index--;
            curr.RemoveAt(curr.Count() - 1);
        }
    } 
}

public static void init()
{
    string[] confidence = new string[] { "High", "Low Variable" };
    string[] goalspec = new string[] { "High", "Low Some" };
    string[] quality = new string[] { "High", "Low Variable" };
    string[] tansSkills = new string[] { "High", "Low some" };
    string[] sitLead = new string[] { "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4" };
    string[] devLev = new string[] { "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4" };
    string[] statReason = new string[] {"In backlog", "Canceled", "Completed" };
    List<List<string>> srs = new List<List<string>>
    {
        confidence.ToList(),
        goalspec.ToList(),
        quality.ToList(),
        tansSkills.ToList(),
        sitLead.ToList(),
        devLev.ToList(),
        statReason.ToList()
    };
    number_elem = srs.Count();
    int[] size = new int[number_elem];
    size[0] = confidence.Count();
    size[1] = goalspec.Count();
    size[2] = quality.Count();
    size[3] = tansSkills.Count();
    size[4] = sitLead.Count();
    size[5] = devLev.Count();
    size[6] = statReason.Count();
    dest = new List<List<string>>();
    List<string> curr = new List<string>();
    combinations(srs, size, curr, 0);
}
```